# Not getting the correct solution of a second order ODE

Tags: differential-equations

This is the original question

My code is

```
kp = 4000; 
vm = 311; 
w = 314*Pi; 
k = 1; 
ki = 1;
DSolve[{y''[x] + (kp*vm*Cos[w*x - y[x]]-2/3 kp*k*vm*Cos[w*x] Cos[y[x]]) y'[x] 
        - ki*vm*Sin[w*x - y[x]] - 2/3 ki*k*vm*Cos[w*x] Sin[y[x]] 
        -kp*vm*w*Cos[w*x - y[x]] == 0, 
        y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 100*Pi}, y[x], x];
```

It has been run for $3$ hours, But it still has no answer.

- march 3 said:"Do you have reason to believe that there is an analytic solution to this differential equation? It doesn't look that way to me. I suggest using NDSolve instead and getting a numerical solution. In that case, what is a proper value for t?"
- xzczd said :"`nsol = NDSolveValue[{y''[ x] + (kp*vm*Cos[w*x - y[x]] - 2/3 kp*k*vm*Cos[w*x]Cos[y[x]]) y'[x] - ki*vm*Sin[w*x - y[x]] - 2/3 ki*k*vm*Cos[w*x] Sin[y[x]] - kp*vm*w*Cos[w*x - y[x]] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 100*Pi}, y, {x, 0, 0.1}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming`  takes about 11 seconds on my laptop"

So I simplified the expression like this

```
y''[x] + kp*vm*Cos[w*x - y[x]]* y'[x] - ki*vm*Sin[w*x - y[x]] - 
  kp*vm*w*Cos[w*x - y[x]] == 0
```

The answer is obviously `y = wx`, but my code produces

```
kp = 2;
vm = 311;
w = 314*Pi;
k = 0;
ki = 100;
nsol = NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + kp*vm*Cos[w*x - y[x]]* y'[x] - 
       ki*vm*Sin[w*x - y[x]] - kp*vm*w*Cos[w*x - y[x]] == 0, 
     y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 100*Pi}, y, {x, 0, 0.1}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
Plot[Mod[nsol[x], 2 Pi], {x, 0, 0.1}]
```

[image]

It is obviosly a wrong answers. Why?

I have found my mistake. The parameter `w` should be set to `100 Pi` instead of the wrong value of `314 Pi`.

Now the result is as shown below.

[image]

Comment: @Shutao TANG Thank you for your edit!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that there is an analytic solution to this differential equation? It doesn't look that way to me. I suggest using `NDSolve` instead and getting a numerical solution. In that case, what is a proper value for `t`?

Comment: Thank you for your advice.I have also tried the NDSolve.Just edit the last "x" to "{x, 0, 30}".But it is stil have no answers.

Comment: I think that `t` should be `x`

Comment: Yes,I made a mistake, I will edit it and run it again.

Comment: I don't know how long does the MMA take to solve this eqn.

Comment: `nsol = NDSolveValue[{y''[
        x] + (kp*vm*Cos[w*x - y[x]] - 2/3 kp*k*vm*Cos[w*x] Cos[y[x]]) y'[x] - 
       ki*vm*Sin[w*x - y[x]] - 2/3 ki*k*vm*Cos[w*x] Sin[y[x]] - 
       kp*vm*w*Cos[w*x - y[x]] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 100*Pi}, y, {x, 0, 0.1}, 
    MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming` takes about 11 seconds on my laptop.

Comment: You forgot about the boundary: `{y'[0] == 100*Pi} /. y -> Function[x, w x] (*False*)`

Comment: Sorry,I dont know what is the bondary. Can you explain it in more details? Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for your explaination!

Comment: So, now, what's your problem?

Comment: I want to get a numerical solution of the eqn, but is seems that MMA can only give an plot of the solution . And I don't know the difference between NDSolve and NDSolveValue

Comment: You need to add something like @xzczd in your comment or I won't get the reminder. The `nsol` is exactly the numerical solution, you can use it like `nsol[0.05]`. To understand the difference between `NDSolve` and `NDSolveValue`, just check the document.

Comment: @xzczd  Thank you！I will use the help document to learn it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Thank for the help with @xzczd ，I want to post a possible answer.
The code is

```
kp = 2;
vm = 311;
w = 100*Pi;
k = 1;
ki = 100;
nsol = NDSolveValue[{y''[
        x] + (kp*vm*Cos[w*x - y[x]] - 
          2/3 kp*k*vm*Cos[w*x] Cos[y[x]]) y'[x] - 
       ki*vm*Sin[w*x - y[x]] - 2/3 ki*k*vm*Cos[w*x] Sin[y[x]] - 
       kp*vm*w*Cos[w*x - y[x]] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 100*Pi}, 
    y, {x, 0, 0.1}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
Plot[Mod[nsol[x], 2 Pi], {x, 0, 0.1}]
```

And the results is:

[image]

It is similar with the result which is offered by the Simulink.